# What are some practical applications of XOR in algorithms

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation, xor

To be honest I am rusty in bit operations.
What I am interested in is the `XOR` operation. Well, I know what it does bitwise, and that it is used in encryption and that we can do swapping without any temporary variable, but I was interested if there are specific approaches in algorithms that `XOR`'s properties fit.
I mean I am interested in practical applications of `XOR` in algorithms (e.g. we could use it to finding unique element among duplicates). Is there a pattern of problems (or a formulation of a problem) that one could see that the use of `XOR` is the way to go? (Same way as there is a pattern when to use binary search?)
Is there some list of practical applications of `XOR` on algorithms that is related to the core algorithm, not simply use it e.g. to do math operations faster like we can use `>>` instead of divide by 2.

Any input is welcome

Comment: Well, every other hashing algorithm (including non-cryptographic ones) uses XOR in one place or another. Does that count, or is it still "just bitfiddling"?

Comment: I was hopping something along the line of best way to solve a problem. Like when you are trying to find unique among duplicates you could use a hashtable but can do it without extra space with `XOR` since duplicates are cancelled out

Comment: **One of the most important question ons the web and it's closed....**

Answer (score 9):

A few examples that came up in my mind:

Toggling bits:

```
int i = 123;
i ^= (1 << 4); // toggle bit 5
```

Some kind of randomness:

```
int i = 123;
for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++)
{
   i = i ^ (i << 1) + i;
   System.out.println(i);
}
```

"Weak Encryption":

```
int b = 235321;
int key = 24552;
int encrypted = b ^ key;
int decrypted = encrypted ^ key; // equals 235321
```

Comment: That is exactly why I wrote "weak".

Comment: BTW, the last one can be extended to encrypting plain text easily (you just need an encoding). *If* the key is random and as long as the input, it's actually a [pretty good cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) in that it's impossible to crack (knowing neither key nor plaintext). If the key is shorter (and thus repeated to fit the length of the input) it can be cracked easily (well, easy for an expert) though - the only remaining problem is creating a one-time pad and getting it to Bob. Cryptographics is fascinating.